# Print a pattern using recursion in Swift

Tags: swift, recursion

I want to print a pattern: first reduce 5 one by one until we reach 0 or negative and then we add 5 until we reach n.

I have tried this code but it stops at 10,5:

```
import Foundation

func printPattern(n : Int) {
    if n <= 0 {
        if n == n {
            return
        } else {
            print(n)
            printPattern(n: n + 5)
        }
    }

    if n > 0 {
        print(n)
        printPattern(n: n - 5)
    }
}

printPattern(n: 10)
```

I want the output to be 10,5,0,5,10.

Comment: This line -> `if n == n` will always be true. Maybe your function needs two arguments, `currentN` and `originalN` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be:

```
func printPattern(n : Int) {

    if n <= 0 {
        print(n)
    }
    else {
        print(n)
        printPattern(n: n - 5)
        print(n)
    }

}
```

So with this call:

```
printPattern(n: 10)
```

The output is:

> ```
> 10
> 5
> 0
> 5
> 10
> ```

The first call to `printPattern` prints the two `10`'s.

The second call to `printPattern` prints the two `5`'s.

The third and final call to `printPattern` prints the `0`.

The recursive call is nested between the two prints in each call which is how you get the pattern.

The calling sequence is like this:

```
printPattern(n: 10)
  print(10)
  printPattern(n: 5)
    print(5)
    printPattern(n: 0)
      print(0)  // base case
    print(5)  // upon return
  print(10) // upon return
```

---

**What are you doing wrong in your function?**

Your function appears to be attempting to judge the direction of adding/subtracting `5` based on whether the current value is positive or zero/negative.  The problem with this is that you would get into a loop of printing `0` and `5` continuously switching directions.  Since you pass `5` going both directions, you need some other way of indicating increasing vs. decreasing.

Your function is currently just outputting `10, 5` because when you get to `0`, the check `if n == n` is always true.  It is checking `if 0 == 0`, not  `if 0 == 10`.  If you want to check against the original value of `n`, you'll need to pass that as a separate input.

This is approximately what you were attempting:

```
func printPattern(n: Int, decreasing: Bool = true, start: Int? = nil) {
    // If there is no start value, use n
    let start = start ?? n

    // recursive base case
    if n > start {
        return
    }

    // if we're already increasing or we have reached zero/negative
    // time to increase
    if !decreasing || n <= 0 {
        print(n)
        printPattern(n: n + 5, decreasing: false, start: start)
    } else {
        // otherwise we are still decreasing
        print(n)
        printPattern(n: n - 5, decreasing: true, start: start)
    }

}

printPattern(n: 10)
```

> ```
> 10
> 5
> 0
> 5
> 10
> ```

Comment: can i have an explanation of this code please? and what was i doing wrong?